# UISegmentedControl image highlighting bug in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an application in which I wanted to customize the segment control using buttons like in Instagram. I had done like this

```
 [[UISegmentedControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
 [[UISegmentedControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

 [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_btn.png"]

                   forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

 [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-sel.png"]
                                     forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                       rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                                              barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel-uns.png"]
                                     forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                                       rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                              barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But when I am selecting the button it is highlighting except the division image. So its looking wired. Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
UIImage *defaultBgImage,*selectedBgImage,*segcontrol_uns,*segcontrol_sel;

if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) 
{
    defaultBgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_bg.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    selectedBgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_btn.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    segcontrol_uns = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-sel.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    segcontrol_sel = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel-uns.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}
else
{
    defaultBgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_bg.png"];
    selectedBgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_btn.png"];
    segcontrol_uns = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-sel.png"];
    segcontrol_sel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel-uns.png"];
}

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:defaultBgImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:selectedBgImage
forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

 [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segcontrol_uns forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

 [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segcontrol_sel forLeftSegmentState: UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: we need to use the images for the hi lighted states also.thats actually i meant for .anyway thanks for ur attempt.if u include that also i will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do "**setBackgroundImage**" for four different states.

1. UIControlStateNormal
2. UIControlStateSelected
3. UIControlStateHighlighted
4. UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted (When pressing already selected segment)

And do "**setDividerImage**" for seven different states.

1. forLeftSegmentState:**UIControlStateNormal**
   rightSegmentState:**UIControlStateSelected**
2. forLeftSegmentState:**UIControlStateSelected** rightSegmentState:**UIControlStateNormal**
3. forLeftSegmentState:**UIControlStateHighlighted** rightSegmentState:**UIControlStateSelected**
4. forLeftSegmentState:**UIControlStateSelected** rightSegmentState:**UIControlStateHighlighted**
5. forLeftSegmentState:**UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted** rightSegmentState:**UIControlStateNormal**
6. forLeftSegmentState:**UIControlStateNormal** rightSegmentState:**UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted**
7. forLeftSegmentState:**UIControlStateNormal** rightSegmentState:**UIControlStateNormal**

Answer (score 0):

You need the following images for three segments
1. segment bg selected 
2. segment bg unselected
3. segment middle, left selected, right unselected 
4. segment middle, left unselected, right selected 
5. segment middle, both left & right selected 
6. segment middle, both left & right unselected

I had written this code for a 3 Segment control. However you can tweak it as per your needs.

```
/* Unselected background */
UIImage *unselectedBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_background_unselected"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:unselectedBackgroundImage
                                       forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                     barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

/* Selected background */
UIImage *selectedBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_background_selected"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:selectedBackgroundImage
                                       forState:UIControlStateSelected
                                     barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

/* Image between two unselected segments */
UIImage *bothUnselectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_middle_unselected"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 0, 15, 0)];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:bothUnselectedImage
                         forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                           rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

/* Image between segment selected on the left and unselected on the right */
UIImage *leftSelectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_middle_left_selected"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 0, 15, 0)];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:leftSelectedImage
                         forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                           rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

/* Image between segment selected on the right and unselected on the left */
UIImage *rightSelectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_middle_right_selected"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 0, 15, 0)];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:rightSelectedImage
                         forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                           rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code fixed it for me:

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[InboxViewController class], nil]  setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gray"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[InboxViewController class], nil]  setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gray"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[InboxViewController class], nil]  setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gray"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[InboxViewController class], nil]  setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gray"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```